# catkin_make install to /opt/groovy|hydro

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [catkin tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/commands/catkin_make) you can define the prefix when using `catkin_make install` in the following way:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/groovy install
```

The question is: how to really install in in my system? because after I do that, the package is installed as `catkin_make install` without any option. So it stays in the same directory. How can I install it in `/opt/ros/groovy`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187114/catkin_make-install-to-/opt/groovy%7Chydro/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2014-07-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin_make` is a fairly thin layer over cmake/make invocations. This means the above command is simply invoking `make install` on the cmake generated Makefiles. The install prefix is the one for the `catkin_make`/`cmake` invocation that generated these make files. If you built your project with `catkin_make build ...` before and then invoke your command above, cmake will not be rerun to regenerate the files (catkin does not currently keep track of which arguments you passed previously).

In short, the following invocation should probably do the right thing:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/groovy install --force-cmake
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-07-19**:
Got it. Cmake was taking the cache. Thanks!